# What are the differences between internal organs between sub-saharan Africans and Northern Europeans

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, population-genetics, morphology

Lets take as examples a typical Norwegian and a typical Nigerian.

In terms of human anatonomy the outer differences are more obvious e.g. (on average)

- White skin vs dark skin
- Pointy nose vs broad nose
- Thin lips vs thicker lips
- Straight hair vs tight curly hair
- Different skull shape
- Height differences
- Different colour eyes or eyelids.

In fact there is almost a difference in every external organ.

There are also some invisible differences such as propensity to sickle cell disease.

But what I hear less about is the differences (in general) between internal organs between populations. Some people even suggest that differences are only "skin deep" between human populations. Which I think goes against evolutionary theory. As why would natural selection stop at skin level? Also, there is a lot of research into skeletal differences but that's easier to do since we can look at a skeletons.

Therefor it seems fairly logical to assume that there would be fairly apparent differences in internal organs between these populations. (I hesitate to use the word 'races') i.e. as apparant as different hair types, or different nose shapes.

I don't mean that one population will have 3 kidneys for example, but I would expect that there would be an obvious shape or size difference between most, if not all internal organs, just as there is a shape, colour or size difference between most external organs.

Is there some research done on this, e.g. a catalogue of differences in internal organs morphology between different populations? Or is it taboo to even ask such questions perhaps?

Edit: One might say, "how would anyone know? Or care?" But, for example, a heart surgeon might find they need different sized instruments dealing with different people. Or surgeons from different continents might compare notes on anatomy. And anatomy textbooks based on just one population might not be representative. Surgeries working on one "race" might not work on others. e.g. if the heart wall was thinner or the colon was longer.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Is it a taboo subject? I thought it might be. Pity societal pressure gets in the way of science.

Comment: I don't know about organ sizes, but it is known that certain population are more prone to develop certain diseases than others. One famous example I'm aware of are the Pima, who developed a very efficient metabolism in response to the available food in their  traditional environment. However, this efficient metabolism in combination with nowadays western diet makes them prone to overweight and related diseases like type two diabetes. There is research in that field, but it's far from being complete.

Comment: I won't consider it a taboo but you must understand that the traditional concept of races is based on superficial appearances. For example it would put all black skinned African people in one group (and so on with other people). Certainly there are differences in different human populations (morphological, anatomical and metabolic). You may rephrase your question on these lines and narrow it down. Be precise and avoid unnecessary explanation of things that you are not interested in.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Well if you say straight hair vs. african curly hair is "superficial" then you might say there would also be "superficial" differences in organs. However, it easy to tell by sight the differences. No-one would mistake a native Nigerian for a native Norwegian. I did narrow it down to Norwegians vs Nigerians. In that case the question is "what are the superficial differences in internal organs between these two people." Sounds like a worrying lack of research in this area!

Comment: @zooby By superficial, I meant what is easily observable (like skin color or hair shape). The easy-to-tell-by-sight differences were the basis of race. Research has found that just because two people look similar doesn't mean that they are genetically more similar. Anyway, by narrowing down I meant that you can make you question precise. I would rephrase the title on the lines of "are there significant differences in the internal anatomy of different human population groups" (and edit the body accordingly). You don't have to narrow it down to the level of comparing Norwegians and Nigerians.

Comment: @WYSIWYG. I think by writing it like that it would make it so vague it would lose most of its meaning unfortunately. Is there anything wrong with asking about 2 specific populations?

Comment: “Propensity to sickle cell disease” is a misleading description of the fact that specific individuals in a population have a mutation that renders them less susceptible to malaria. Sicilians also have individuals in their population with a different mutation that serves the same function, although causes a different disease in homozygotes. In neither case is this a universal feature of the populations like skin pigmentation.

Comment: @zooby nothing wrong in asking about these specific groups. However, your actual question can be answered with respect to any two groups (not necessarily the ones you mentioned). Also note that lifestyle will also affect the organ sizes. There is some correlation between body weight and size of some organs (studies done in different populatins). However, I don't think anyone has investigated if these relationships are significantly different between different populations (after accounting for factors such as lifestyle and diet).

Comment: Yes, but I was just interested in these two particular groups as they have more obvious outward differences than, say, a the differences beteween Sweden and Norway, for example. So the differences should be more pronounced. It would be fascinating if it was found, for example, that in one population the left ventricle was larger than the right and other populations the reverse was true (as a made up example). In a similar manner that a nose might be wider than it is tall or vice versa.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask on a medical site. Someone doing autopsies in a country with a population of diverse origins would know. I imagine the answer is no or it would have been observed and reported. I see nothing wrong with your question, just that you are addressing it to a group that is unlikely to have experience in this area.

Comment: @David. Thanks, I might try.